# Cannot set ref on like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Im trying to add a like button to my web app that is currently in development on localhost. 
Ive set the ref attribute for fb:like and whilst i can like my websites page and see it in on my test-users facebook wall, the link posted does not contain any params such as fb_ref etc. Even clicking the link and checking my servers logs shows no params were sent.

I dont know what im doing wrong. Due to extensive testing facebook requires me to "confirm" I want to like something each time I click on the like button (a measure to thrwart spammers I believe). Does that have anything to do with it? I also turned on sandbox mode.

here is the button

```
<fb:like href="localhost:3000" ref="atrackingcode" send="false" show_faces="false" width="450" class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget"></fb:like>
```

here is the sdk intialization

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'SECRET-SO-BOO-HOO',
    channelUrl : '//localhost:3000/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
};

(function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: As a guess, there's no fb_ref because facebook cannot lint the page properly since it is not on a publicly accessible website.